# Arrow Function Declaration | Redux | =>

Tags: javascript, redux, arrow-functions

Why do we have `=>` twice. Not able to understand the arrow function declaration.

```
const asyncFunctionMiddleware = storeAPI => next => action => {
  // If the "action" is actually a function instead...
  if (typeof action === 'function') {
    // then call the function and pass `dispatch` and `getState` as arguments
    return action(storeAPI.dispatch, storeAPI.getState)
  }

  // Otherwise, it's a normal action - send it onwards
  return next(action)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`asyncFunctionMiddleware` takes one argument `storeAPI` and returns an unnamed function. This unnamed function takes one argument `next` and returns another unnamed function. This unnamed function takes one argument `action` and returns a value.